# How to assert a pyparsing.ParseResults content?

Tags: unit-testing, pyparsing

I would like to validate using Python `assert` on the `pyparsing.ParseResults` class and its content.

A working snippet of Python pyparsing code is given here:

```
import pyparsing as pp
first = pp.Word(pp.srange('[a-zA-Z]'), exact=1)
rest = pp.Optional(pp.Word(pp.srange('[_0-9a-zA-Zz]')))
keyName = pp.Combine(first + rest)
```

A simple printout is (and gets misleading):

```
print keyName.parseString("Abc_de")
['Abc_de']
#
print ['Abc_de']
['Abc_de']
```

Of course, the following assert fails:

```
# Unit test that is faulty
assert keyName.parseString("Abc_de") == ['Abc_de']
```

Unit test is failing... because the type of `['Abc_de']` is a `list` whereas the type of `keyName.parseString("Abc_de"))` is a `<class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>`.

What method should I be calling so that assertion can easily be made?

Comment: You can also simplify the definition of `keyName` using the 2-argument form of `Word`: `keyname = pp.Word(pp.srange('[a-zA-Z]'), pp.srange('[_0-9a-zA-Z]'))`.  The first arg is a string of the characters that are allowed leading characters, and the second arg is a list of allowed (but not required) body characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `asList` method on the result returned by `parseString`.

```
import pyparsing as pp
first = pp.Word(pp.srange('[a-zA-Z]'), exact=1)
rest = pp.Optional(pp.Word(pp.srange('[_0-9a-zA-Zz]')))
keyName = pp.Combine(first + rest)

assert keyName.parseString('Abc_de').asList() == ['Abc_de']
```

Comment: Sorry, I left out the `assert`.

Comment: `asList` is actually a method on the ParseResults returned by parseString, not on parseString itself, but this is the right way to go.